# Sending multi-var dictionary via get in google app engine; python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, get

I recently, started working on the google app engine and am facing the following problem:

I have a main.py where my user sees his own comments + those of others. Now, I need to add an EditComment.py where a user is directed when he wants to edit his code.

I am working with the guestbook application only, and to actually fetch the selected comment I need both guestbook name and the content of the comment. How do I create this url?

In other words, I need to create a url like

```
 \edit?guestbook="Family"&content="helloworld"
```

I tried this

```
//I need to send guestbook_name and content of greeting in order to fetch the row from
//the database
//So, I show the text of the greeting and give a url to edit page 

content_toSend = {'guestbook_name':guestbook_name,'content':greeting.content}

self.response.write('<blockquote><a href="/edit?%s">%s</a></blockquote>' %
                            (content_toSend,greeting.content))

//But the other side handler receives only the first variable of the dict in the get request
```

so that the user can click on a greeting and be directed to the edit page. But the get request just sends the first var(guestbook_name) in the url. How do I send the whole dictionary?

Edit : I had tired urllib.urlencode but the handler in webapp2 requires a dict and so that didn't work

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting as it is ambiguous the way it is posted?

Comment: I tried to do so. I hope its clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html?highlight=urllib#urllib.urlencode) of `urllib` standard library can be useful.

edit with example:

```
content_toSend = urllib.urlencode({
    'guestbook_name' : guestbook_name,
    'content' : greeting.content
    })
```

Comment: I tried that, but apparently the request handlers require a dictionary and so it didn't work

Comment: Thanks, I was trying encode content_toSend and I think that was where the error was

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are going to have these two variables in dictionary why dont u try this

```
self.response.write('<blockquote><a href="/edit?guestbook=%s&content=%s">%s</a></blockquote>' %
                        (content_toSend['guestbook_name'],content_toSend['content'],greeting.content))
```